# Access to updated DOM objects within an anonymous function passed to LiveQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, livequery

I have 2 input text form fields, and I would like to use Live Query and the values of both fields to GET a particular URI via AJAX.  Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
$('.AutoComplete').livequery(function () {
    var state = $('#state').val();
    $(this).autocomplete(
        'http://www.example.com/getcities/' + state,
        {
            minChars: 1,
            multiple: false,
            scrollHeight: 100,
            selectFirst: true
        }
     );
 });
```

In the example, I am retrieving the value of the form element with id "state", storing this in the state variable, then constructing my URI using that variable.  The other form field ("city") is the **AutoComplete** field triggering the example function call.

The problem I run into is that the value of the "state" variable does not change if the state form field has been modified by the user after the initial page load.  The value of the state variable seems doomed to be its initial/default value for the life of the page.

Has anyone else run into this?  Are there any work-arounds that don't involve having to muck around with javascript events?

Comment: Avoid livequery, it's inefficient

Comment: Expanding on Raynos' note, check out `.on()`, http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events